# How to define column name in node bookshelf models?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, model, bookshelf.js

I'm using `Bookshelf` in my `NodeJs` application for database manipulation

I need when I execute:

```
User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users'
});

new User({
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Paul"
}).save();
```

It will need saving values in 'first_name' and 'last_name' columns

How to can I do define this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there is no built in method to do this. However I just asked this in #bookshelf irc and somebody told me :)

```
var STRING_CAMELIZE_REGEXP = (/(\-|_|\.|\s)+(.)?/g);
var STRING_UNDERSCORE_REGEXP_1 = (/([a-z\d])([A-Z]+)/g);
var STRING_UNDERSCORE_REGEXP_2 = (/\-|\s+/g);

function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(STRING_CAMELIZE_REGEXP, function(match, separator, chr) {
    return chr ? chr.toUpperCase() : '';
  }).replace(/^([A-Z])/, function(match, separator, chr) {
    return match.toLowerCase();
  });
}

function underscore(str) {
  return str.replace(STRING_UNDERSCORE_REGEXP_1, '$1_$2').
    replace(STRING_UNDERSCORE_REGEXP_2, '_').toLowerCase();
}


var _ = require('lodash');
var Podcast = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  parse: function(attrs) {
    return _.reduce(attrs, function(memo, val, key) {
      memo[camelize(key)] = val;
      return memo;
    }, {});
  },
  format: function(attrs) {
    return _.reduce(attrs, function(memo, val, key) {
      memo[underscore(key)] = val;
      return memo;
    }, {});
  }
});


var p = new Podcast();
p.set('lastUpdated', new Date());
```

To elaborate, this will turn camelCase into snake_case.

Comment: Hello, where do you put this one? I need something like this one.